# Need help understanding the tuple relational calculus

Tags: databases, relational-calculus, tuple-relational-calculus

We say that a query in a TRC is a statement of the form $\{T: P(T)\}$, where $T$ is a tuple variable and $P(T)$ is a formula.

Now my question is, what are the possible tuples $T$ to be tested i.e., what are the types and values for tested tuples.

As far as I know in set theory and in particular in set builder notation the variables should come from another well-defined set.

Comment: There are many TRCs. You need to define what type "tuple" is in yours. That will give you your "well-defined set".

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_relational_calculus):

A tuple is of the form $T=(D,R,h)$ where $D$ is the domain, $R$ is a set of relation names, and $h$ is a mapping that associates a column name to each relation in $R$. To represent a tuple, we can see $D$ as the set of keys, and $R$ the table associated with those set of keys, and $h$ the column names of the table.